# Loop and Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

Can I have 2 initializers, 2 conditions, 2 iterators?

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator){
    body
}
```

I am asking this because I want to compare 2 arrays

```
int[] v1 = new int[10];
int[] v2 = new int[10];

for(int i=0; int j=v2.Length; i<v1.Length; j>0; i++; j--)
{
     if(v1[i]==v2[j])
     {
        //do something
     }
}
```

Comment: yes - separate with a comma instead of semi-colon: `for(int i=0, int j=v2.Length; i<v1.Length, j>0; i++, j--)`

Comment: You could just use 1 variable though. if(v1[i]==v2[v2.Length - i]) or similar

Comment: @AndrewS that doesnt compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, you can declare and initialize multiple loop variables, but they need to have the same type. Further, you cant have multiple conditions, but you can combine them via logical operators:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < v1.Length && j > 0; i++, j++  )
{
    if (v1[i] == v2[j])
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

what also works is to initialize earlier declared variables of different types:

```
int i; double j;
for ( i = 0, j = 1.5; ... )
```